# Как правильно прописать наследование?

Tags: наследование, css

Как правильно прописать наследование в `css`?

```
tbody tr td [что должно быть здесь?] {text-align: center}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы третий тег `<td>` выравнивался по центру

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таблицы задайте класс (например, "`table`") и в CSS пишите:

```
.table td:nth-child(3) { text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе пример:

```
td:nth-last-child(2n+1) {
background: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет фона */
   }
```

для каждого нечетного td устанавливает фон.